# What am I supposed to be returning to avoid error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘seg’?

Tags: c, struct, return

So in my code seg is the typedef name of a structure I made in a header file. The heading of the function is correct -- that was given -- but I am unsure if I am following the wanted return type which is a *seg (or a struct seg pointer). 
I get the error: avoid error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘seg’? which I cannot figure out. If anyone could guide me thanks. thanks for the time and help.

```
*seg  whichseg(int j){
    int seg_node_num = (int)ceil(j/(float)BITS_PER_SEG);
    int i = 1;
    seg *seg_node;
    seg_node = (seg*)malloc(sizeOf(seg));
    for(seg_node = head; i <= seg_node_num; seg_node = seg_node.next)
    {
        i++;
    }
    return seg_node; }
```

this is the header file sorry for not putting it earlier 
'

```
    typedef struct _seg {  /* definition of new type "seg" */
        int  bits[256];
        struct _seg  *next,*prev;        
          }seg  ;

    EXTERN int NSegs;

    EXTERN seg *head;
```

Comment: The heading of the function is not correct. It should be `seg*` not `*seg`.

Comment: Please read [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `*` goes after the type name, `seg*` is a type, while `*seg` it something different.

Actually `*seg` would mean "dereference the variable named `seg`" and `*` would be used as an unary operator in that situation. Which is not the case in your case.

Comment: When I do that, I get the error: expected expression before ‘seg’.

Comment: Try like this `struct seg *whichseg(int j)`. If it works, please post the rest of the code the next time, like the struct definition and whether or not there is a `typedef`.

Comment: This is how it was give:

Comment: '   typedef struct _seg {  /* definition of new type "seg" */
      int  bits[256];
      struct _seg  *next,*prev;        
        }seg  ;'

Comment: I've put the header file now

Comment: hello iharob, i did what you said and now I get this: slides.c:52: error: expected expression before ‘seg’
slides.c:57: warning: return from incompatible pointer type

Comment: Please post the code before `seg *whichseg(int j)`.

Comment: I apologize for the mix up, but the line that is causing the error is now this seg_node = (seg*)malloc(sizeOf(seg)); this is what requires an expected expression

Comment: sorry for everything this error was due to capitalizing O in sizeOf

Comment: @Chris, I don't want points. I would love you to stop casting `malloc()`. Read the link in my comment on your question please.